# Should I still escape? $_GET and XSS, SQL Injection and other PHP Security Concerns

Tags: php, security, sql-injection, mysql-real-escape-string, xss

If I am retrieving data with $_GET from the URL string and not displaying that data back on a webpage or doing any SQL actions with it, should I still consider using escape, regular expression and other security code? The string could contain any char.

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Depends. What are you doing with this data? Using in `if` ?

Comment: What *are* you doing with it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is "filter input, escape output" still valid with PDO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4218136/is-filter-input-escape-output-still-valid-with-pdo)

Comment: Also, here's a relevant blog post: [Web Application Security Intro](http://blog.ircmaxell.com/2011/03/what-is-security-web-application.html) (from my blog)...

Comment: I am taking that string and passing it to a stand alone application.

Answer (score 2):

if you are not outputting the string or passing it to another program (sql, open file, …) you don't need to escape it.

Comment: what if im passing it to a stand along application (that is not a browser, sql,..)?

Comment: @newphper: escape it to match the rules of the application. how are you passing it to the application? using [`system`](http://php.net/system) or [`exec`](http://php.net/exec) or [`passthru`](http://php.net/passthru) functions? (or backtick operator in php)? then you HAVE TO escape them. otherwise you are allowing everyone to execute arbitrary commands on your system as the user php is run from. [`escapeshellarg`](http://php.net/escapeshellarg) might be a good starting point

Comment: From what i understand, the data is passed onto the application as a json blob. Sorry, I am still figuring this out.

Comment: even for json objects use `escapeshellarg` (json format uses many shell special characters: `{};"'`)! better safe than sorry

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using the URL param in a SQL statement it can not be used as a SQL injection.

Comment: If you're using it to output it on the page, however, there's another danger (XSS)

Comment: @Vladislav - True, and I was originally going to mention that, but he says he is not outputting the param.