# What is the proper format to setup and run a safe mysql query?

Tags: php, mysql, security, pdo

Ive read alot of different ideas lately on how to do this. Im running php 5.5 and mysql 5.6, and Im using PDO prepared statements.

PDO is supposed to not require sanitation beforehand, so why do I see so many references to filter_input and filter_var?

Is FIEO relevant with PDO? Below is a simple example of a query and echo. How should i ultimately set it up differently?

```
$name = "John";
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT `name` FROM `users` WHERE `name`=?");
$query->bindValue(1, $name);

try{
    $query->execute();
    $row = $query->fetch();
} catch(PDOException $e){
    die($e->getMessage());
}

echo "Name is " . $row['name'] . ".";
```

Im looking forward to finally understanding proper coding for security.

Comment: you will never *finally* understand proper coding for security

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4218136/is-filter-input-escape-output-still-valid-with-pdo

Comment: You could use named parameters. Apart of that it's fine

Comment: What about FIEO? What if the example is more complex such as a variable is a string or html?

Answer (score 0):

`filter_var` isn't **just** for sanitizing input; there are also validation filters that can be used for type checking (http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php) and as processing instructions (http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.flags.php).

*On a tangential note:*

There's also the whole concept of **using** the stored data; just because you may be more or less safe against SQL injection **doesn't** mean your data can then be **consumed** safely. You still have to make sure your data doesn't contain malicious content (like, for instance, checking for encoded text that renders out as executable JavaScript when accepting HTML content from a user).

If you want to see some examples of things to watch out for in the example I mention above, I found the test suite for the HtmlSanitizer library very interesting: https://github.com/mganss/HtmlSanitizer/blob/master/HtmlSanitizer.Tests/Tests.cs

Answer (score -1):

Variables passed as arguments to prepared statements will automatically be escaped by the underlying driver which helps to prevent SQL injection.

Although Prepared Statements helps in defending against SQL Injection, there are possibilities of SQL Injection attacks through inappropriate usage of Prepared Statements

```
  String strUserName = //retrieved from webpage via text field 
  $query = $db->prepare("SELECT `name` FROM `users` WHERE `name`=strUserName ");
```